# While building project in circleci 2.0 getting apturl==0.5.2 missing error

Tags: django, python-3.x, github, circleci

I have integrated my github project with circleci 2.0. but when i run build from circleci dashboard, i am getting this error.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2
>   (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
>       No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))

Here is my **config.yml**

```
# Python CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-python/ for more 
details
#
version: 2
jobs:
build:
  docker:
   # specify the version you desire here
  # use `-browsers` prefix for selenium tests, e.g. `3.6.1-browsers`
  - image: circleci/python:3.6.1

  # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
  # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
  # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
  # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

working_directory: ~/Amazon_customers

steps:
  - checkout

  # Download and cache dependencies
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
      - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}
      # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
      - v1-dependencies-

  - run:
      name: install dependencies
      command: |
        pipenv install

  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - ./venv
      key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}

  # run tests!
  # this example uses Django's built-in test-runner
  # other common Python testing frameworks include pytest and nose
  # https://pytest.org
  # https://nose.readthedocs.io
  - run:
      name: run tests
      command: |
        . venv/bin/activate
        python manage.py test

  - store_artifacts:
      path: test-reports
      destination: test-reports
```

And this is my **requirements.txt** file:

```
coverage==4.5.1
Django==2.0.6
djangorestframework==3.8.2
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pytz==2018.4
```

I don't have any apturl==0.5.2 in requirements.txt.How can i resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
version: 2
jobs:
 build:
  working_directory: ~/tt-server
docker:
  - image: circleci/python3.5
    environment:
        # Enviroment Variables
steps:
  - checkout
  - run:
      command: pipenv install
  - run:
      command: "echo mkdir /tmp/artifacts"
  - run:
      command: |
        pipenv run "coverage run manage.py test --parallel=4"
        pipenv run "coverage combine"
        pipenv run "coverage report -m"
        pipenv run "coverage html -d /tmp/artifacts"
        pipenv run "coveralls"
  - store_artifacts:
      path: /tmp/artifacts
```

replace your congig.yml with this code.Also remove pkg-resources==0.0.0 from **requiremnets.txt**